# How can I get all rows with "where" clause from 4 database tables and put them in response API list of objects?

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, response, one-to-many

How can i get all rows with "where id=123" filter from DB?
I have 4 tables (t1-< t2, t2-<t3, t3-<t4 - from first table to last OneToMaNY) in DB and put it in response api List of objects?

I try to use @Query in JpaRepository interface for my entity, but it doesn't work.

All 4 tables were created from entity classes with annotations

first entity T1 have
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set t2;

second entity T2 have

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set t3;

second entity T3 have

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<T4> t4;
```

Response api is List which include all fields from tables above

Request has only one parameter in path {id}, using for sort rows in db in "where" operator

How can i get all rows with "where" filter from 4 tables (t1-< t2, t2-<t3, t3-<t4) in DB and put it in response api List of objects?

Tried to find all rows from tables in single select, without join

Comment: This is a method in service class:

List<T1> method = T1Repository.findByCode(id);

// id - we get from request , string

And JpaRepository interface:

public interface T1Repository extends JpaRepository<T1,Integer> {

    @Query("select m from T1 m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.T2")
    List<T1> findByCode(String id);

}

How can i change @Query for filtering by id from request?

P.S. this one works and find all rows, but without filtering

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.